# Adding background image to iCarousel menue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, icarousel

I want to make a rotating wheel in my iOS App. Always the top item should be the selected item. I used [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) to make the wheel. But my problem is I want to add a background image for the wheel just like in this picture. But I don't understand how to do it. I just added an `UIImageView`under the `iCarousel`but its not a good way to do it. Because my wheel radius is changing according to the device size.

What is the best way I can do this. This is what I want to do.
[image]

Comment: you can try setting constraints for your UIImageView such that the image will resize according to device size. I think this will do.